# Firebase connection with multiple Node.js behind AWS/ALB load balancer and Nginx

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, firebase, nginx

I need to connect Firebase to a Node setup on AWS/Elastic Beanstalk. There are 1-4 Node servers, behind an ALB load balancer and an Nginx proxy. Firebase uses WSS protocol (hence the need for ALB, because the regular ELB does not support sockets). When a Node instance authenticates with Firebase it gets a socket the app can listen to.

My question: Since there could be any of the Node servers communicating with Firebase, how can the sockets be made sticky, so that regardless of which of the Node servers opened a socket, it will be the right socket for each communication?

Thanks!

ZE

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [Sticky sessions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) in AWS ALB for WSS protocol to work and send traffic to the same EC2 instance over a period of time.

Also note that you need to configure stickiness at Target Group level.

> I created a 2nd Target Group call "xxxSocket" with Stickiness enabled,
>   and leaving the 1st Target Group "xxxHTTP" without Stickiness
>   (default). Finally, in my Application Load Balancer, I added a new
>   Rule to have "Path Pattern" = /socket.io then route to Target Group
>   "xxxSocket", leaving the default pattern route to "xxxHTTP".

Reference: [AWS Forum Anyone gotten the new Application Load Balancer to work with websockets?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=736038)

Also the WebSockets connections are inherently sticky.

> WebSockets connections are inherently sticky. If the client requests a
>   connection upgrade to WebSockets, the target that returns an HTTP 101
>   status code to accept the connection upgrade is the target used in the
>   WebSockets connection. After the WebSockets upgrade is complete,
>   cookie-based stickiness is not used.

Reference: [Target Groups for Your Application Load Balancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html)

Comment: Thanks Ashan, following your note I looked up AWS Target Group and indeed my ALB does not currently have a Target Group, but there is something else in the Target Group docs: It says "WebSockets connections are inherently sticky. If the client requests a connection upgrade to WebSockets, the target that returns an HTTP 101 status code to accept the connection upgrade is the target used in the WebSockets connection. After the WebSockets upgrade is complete, cookie-based stickiness is not used."

Comment: Can you also share the reference link so that I can update the answer?

Comment: Updated the answer with your info and reference. Thanks @zi88

Comment: Its under "sticky session": http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One query after defining rule in ALB listener to port 3000 how i can display the port as well on url (like this "https://example.com:3000"). I am using the socket.io 2.1.1 and it is working (like this "https://example.com/socket.io/") with ALB rule path defined but i want to be display like "https://example.com:3000". Any idea how i can achieve this? Help will be appreciated. thanks!